# How to use recaptcha without Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have been making a file sharing website for quite a while and I want to implement recaptcha when people register to the website. The problem is that I can't use Flask-WTF because I will have to change a lot of my code (I have been programming without it).

I have found this Flask recaptcha that doesn't include the use of Flask-WTF but I can't seem to make it work (it doesn't show the recaptcha itself):

https://github.com/mardix/flask-recaptcha

I have followed step by step and still, it doesn't work. The only thing that I didn't do is the config.

EDIT:
The captcha is not working. Everytime that I enter the right info for the registration and mark the captcha, it says that the username/password is incorrect. If I don't mark it, it does the same.

Here is the captcha code (the others worked before):

```
recaptcha = ReCaptcha(app=app)

if recaptcha.verify() is False:
            flash('Captcha is incorrect')
            return redirect(url_for('register'))

    <div id="captcha"">
        {{ recaptcha }} - HTML PART
    </div>
```

EDIT: After getting help from Nurzhan, I have changed the code and the captcha always returns false, no matter what.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is kind of hard to tell where it breaks. Maybe include the route and the template? Also the config might be necessary for the extension to work at all. Again without seeing your actual code there is no way for us to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't try the config, but you need to indicate the keys in order to make your recaptcha work. These 2 options are NOT optional in the config:

```
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY : Public key

RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY: Private key
```

Set them with proper values and it see if it works.

**EDIT:**

It's working now. This is app.py:

```
import requests
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_recaptcha import ReCaptcha

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update({'RECAPTCHA_ENABLED': True,
                   'RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY':
                       'site_key',
                   'RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY':
                       'secret_key'})


recaptcha = ReCaptcha(app=app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    print('SUBMIT CALLED')
    username = ''
    password = ''

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

    print(request.form)

    if username == 'username' and password == 'password':
        print('CREDENTIALS ARE OK')

        r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
                          data = {'secret' :
                                  'secret_key',
                                  'response' :
                                  request.form['g-recaptcha-response']})

        google_response = json.loads(r.text)
        print('JSON: ', google_response)

        if google_response['success']:
            print('SUCCESS')
            return render_template('profile.html')
        else:
            # FAILED
            print('FAILED')
            return render_template('index.html')


#        if recaptcha.verify():
#            # SUCCESS

app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>

<h1>Flask Recaptcha</h1>

<p>Flask Recaptcha Test</p>

<form method="post" action="/submit">
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password">

  {{ recaptcha }}

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site_key"></div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the profile.html page if you pass the validation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>

<h1>Profile page</h1>

<p>Registration is ok</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't make `recaptcha.verify()` work. In the official docs of Google Recaptcha it is stated that you need to send a post request to google recaptcha api separately after the client submits your form with your `secret_key` and `g-recaptcha-response` which you receive when user puts a tick in recaptcha.

Note that this is just an example code. You need to add your own site_key and secret_key to the `app.py` and `index.html` and also add a proper checking of user credentials for the registation like double entering  password etc.

Comment: What values do I need to put into the keys?

Comment: @T.Simkin Read this: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro. It should explain how to get one.

Comment: It works now, thank you very much! know I just need to figure out how to align it with the other settings :)

Comment: I have another problem. The reCaptcha is used in registration. If I enter everything correctly and I didn't tick the reCaptcha, it says that there is a problem with the username/password instead of the reCaptcha. Here is the code:            if recaptcha.verify() is False:
                flash('Captcha is incorrect')
                return redirect(url_for('register'))

Comment: @T.Simkin I need to look at this problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of the help but I still have problems. Can I somehow contact your privately? as you can see, this is my first time doing a project and my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: @T.Simkin, The solution I provided is working. Just read it more attentively.